# Unable to Login to Facebook for Developers

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I don't use Facebook, so I had to create an account in order to integrate a Facebook Login into our project. I setup the developer account and took down the App Id and App Secret. The response when I try to connect to Facebook currently is:

> Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's
>   domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains
>   of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings.

So I would like to try updating the domains listed. However when I attempted to login I was prompted to provide a picture of myself (which I did) then given this message:

> You Can't Log In Right 
>   Now Thanks for sending your photo. We'll get in
>   touch with you soon after we've reviewed it. Right now, your account
>   has been disabled as a security precaution.

No timeline, no further information. Any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing called Developer Account. You are only allowed to have one Facebook account.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: If this isn't relevant to other users I'll take it down @WizKid

Comment: It isn't relevant. Stack Overflow is for coding. Your question has nothing to do with coding.

Comment: Uhm, no that's not true. Stack Overflow exists to help software developers. "Founded in 2008, Stack Overflow is the largest, most trusted online community for developers to learn, share their knowledge, and build their careers. More than 50 million professional and aspiring programmers visit Stack Overflow each month to help solve coding problems, develop new skills, and find job opportunities."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Facebook cleared me for access, without notification.